# Looping through object for instance variable - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, instance, swiper.js

I am trying to have to two swiper carousels in on a single page.

So if i use the below instance method the carousel works fine **( Single carousel in a page )**

```
mySwiper  = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
 //conditions
  slidesPerView: slides_per_view,
});
```

but when i have two swiper carousels in a page both even though they have different conditions they both behave same. That's my main problem. I am able to set the value `slides_per_view` with php.

Say if i added two carousels the behave the same though i have set `slides_per_view` different for them.

in my HTML there is

```
data-settings = { slides_per_view:3 } // for first carousel
data-settings = { slides_per_view:6 } // for Second carousel

var cggowl_jav_info_cont = $scope.find('.cggowl-row');
var cgggowl_settings = cggowl_jav_info_cont.data('settings');
console.log( cgggowl_settings ); //this shows the two objects with slides_per_view as 3 and 6
```

Now i want two new instances of the Swiper with the information contained in the `cgggowl_settings` variable so that i can avoid conflict there

```
mySwiper  = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
     //conditions
      slidesPerView: slides_per_view,
    });
```

Comment: Your variables names seem like a bad practice, especially when asking people who don't know your code and only see a fragment of it

Comment: @GalAbra Hello, Sorry. may i know which part of code confused you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was referring the variables `cgggowl...`

Comment: This question is very unclear. You say you have two objects, but you just give two names that are the same: `slidesperview`. I suspect you just need to put your objects in an array, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: "both objects in the loop". What loop?

Comment: @Barmar okay, i have updated my question with more details. Please have a check. by loop, i meant two instances

Comment: @GalAbra Thanks. Sorry, i am new to this. I have updated my question

Comment: `data-settings` is not a valid variable name. Anyway, you're overwriting the variable when you do the second assignment. Try creating an array: `data_settings = [{slides_per_view: 3}, {slides_per_view: 6}]`

Comment: Then you can loop over the array elements, or index them as `data_settings[i]`.

Comment: @Barmar `data-setting` is not actually a variable it is a html data actually similar to class, id,style.. there will be two objects so do i have to make an array out of it?

Comment: Please post actual HTML and JavaScript so we can see what you're really doing. It's hard to tell from tiny snippets like this.

Comment: You should probably be using something like `$(this).data("settings")` to get the data for the current row. You can use that in an event handler attached to the element, or in a `.each()` loop.

Comment: @Barmar thank you very much. that solves my problem :)